# Webpack dev server compile on run-time without initial bundling

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Is there a way to make webpack dev server compile a bundle request on run time instead of compile time?

For example, imagine I've got the following:

**entry.js**

```
function loadMyModule(moduleName){
  require(`bundle-loader!./mymodules/${moduleName}.js`);
}

setTimeout(()=>loadMyModule('helloWorld'), 2000);
```

**What happens now**

Running the dev server will webpack entry.js by code splitting the bundle. The module 'helloWorld' will be put into a separate bundle.

**The problem**

The code splitting happens on *build time*. In other words, I have to wait for webpack to finish packing everything first. If I have a lot of modules in `./mymodules` directory, it will take a long time before webpack dev server can serve a hot reload environment. Subsequent saves will trigger a hot reload and will only recompile the required bundle.

**The question**

Is there a way to tell webpack dev server "if you haven't got this bundle, compile it first then serve it"? This will mean the initial compile will be nearly instant because webpack won't have to compile and code split everything. Only after the setTimeout has finished, a bundle will be created on the fly and served. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I usually set up a "build:dev" task that does the development build (same as webpack-dev-server with writeToDisk: true), and then start dev server - that way it simulates your later case, where WDS does not have to rebuild everything from scratch.

You can try that.